# find supremum and infimum of sets (and min/max if they exist)

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I need help with finding the supremum
I don't really understand even how to start

$B=\lbrace{\frac{m}{m+n} : m,n \in N\rbrace}$

$C=\lbrace{\frac{mn}{4m^2+n^2}:m \in Z, n \in N\rbrace}$

Comment: Try substituting in different numbers, such as the smallest $m$ and $n$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

As $m,n>0$, we have $m<m+n$, and then $\frac{m}{m+n}<1$. 
Also $0$ is a lower bound (since everything is positive). And it is the infimum, as $1/(1+n)\to 0$. Try similarly to get $sup(C)$ and $inf(C)$

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but my phone dont allow me to write a comment, so I decided to write here a hint for  $C$. Note that $0\leq (2m+n)^2=4m^2+4mn+n^2$, therefore dividing by  $ 4m^2+n^2    $ which is not zero, 
$$ -1\leq \frac{4mn}{ 4m^2+n^2}   $$

Comment: how you note that

Comment: Because $x^2\geq 0$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Now take $x=2m+n$.